# Django create effectively sitemap

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to create effectively sitemap like this;

```
sitename.com/post-sitemap.xml
sitename.com/team-sitemap.xml
```

How can i do ?

sitemaps.py

```
class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.published()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.created_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommended sitemap structure

```
https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

`sitemap.xml` can contain sub sitemaps for example

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.google.com/gmail/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.google.com/forms/sitemaps.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.google.com/slides/sitemaps.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.google.com/sheets/sitemaps.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

generating sitemaps in django

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import views

sitemaps = {
    'team': TeamSitemap, 'post': PostSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml', views.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    path('sitemap-<section>.xml', views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
         name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```